# Visualization of typearea DIV grid?

Tags: typearea

In the KOMA-Script documentation (`scrguide-en.pdf`/`scrguien.pdf`), figure 2.1 is a nice illustration of how `typearea`’s `DIV` box construction works:

[image: KOMA-Script documentation figure 2.1]

Is there some way (e. g. a package option) to get the same visualization of the box grid in an arbitrary document, showing the actual `typearea` settings used?

Comment: @Zarko Well, that doesn’t show the `typearea`-specific box construction (see the numbered boxes in the image). I guess it could be used to “manually” measure and count the boxes…

Comment: I've send a feature request to add a corresponding debugging option to the KOMA-Script author. But he needs more information about the purpose. So maybe you should contact him yourself.

Comment: BTW: The names of the KOMA-Script manuals have been changed. With the current release these are no longer `scrguien.pdf` and `scrguide.pdf` but `scrguide-en.pdf` and `scrguide-de.pdf`, as shown in https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script

Comment: @cabohah Ah, I see about the file names – that’s a bit of a shame, I always found them funny. Well my question was mainly if something like this exists, or if there’s a simple way to rig something up – as you suggest, for debugging purposes, just to confirm that `typearea` isn’t doing something I’m not expecting. It would be convenient, but probably not worth it for Markus Kohm to implement just for me.

Comment: You could just adapt the source of the images in the manuals. The sources are part of the distribution. See `typearea-en.tex` or `typearea-de.tex`.

Comment: @cabohah I did check the manual source, but the images are just produced manually in a `picture` environment. That doesn’t help with translating it to the actual document page.